# Azure DevOps How to run a Linux Docker container on Windows Hosted agent

Tags: selenium, docker, azure-devops

Is there a way to run Linux Docker images in a Windows Hosted Agent (Hosted Windows Container as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts&tabs=yaml))?

I want to run Linux Selenium Containers hosted in Docker Hub on an Azure DevOps Hosted Agent. I need to run them on a Windows Host because the next tasks in the pipeline (eg. running VS Tests) require a Windows Host.

Comment: Consider splitting these tasks across multiple jobs - each job can run on a different agent, but they're still a part of the same pipeline. 
for files that need to be shared between jobs (i.e. output of one job is consumed by the next job), use pipeline artifacts.

Comment: The last time I checked, this was not possible. Tasks had to run in the same agent under a pipeline. However, I'll check again just in case.